# configuration for devise with omniauth-saml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, saml

After configure, i tried to start the server and said this:

Wrong OmniAuth configuration. If you are getting this exception, it means that either:

```
You are manually setting OmniAuth.config.path_prefix and it doesn't match the Devise one
You are setting :omniauthable in more than one model
You changed your Devise routes/OmniAuth setting and haven't restarted your server my-profile-configuration/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:471:in `set_omniauth_path_prefix!
```

I have this on my user model

```
devise :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :database_authenticatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:saml]
```

I follow the instructions include when it says to follow omniauth facebook example and got this. What would be done?

Any good configuration for Device with SAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **config/initializers/devise.rb** uncomment a line on the bottom that says something like:

```
# When using omniauth, Devise cannot automatically set Omniauth path,
# so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
# config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/api/users/auth'
```